# POST key=value pair in siege

Tags: benchmarking, apachebench, siege

First of all I am not getting POST worked in siege,

```
siege https://apicdntest.fadv.com/orders/kelly POST
```

This does not hit the URL, but when I remove the POST key, then it hits the URL with GET

What I exactly need is I want hit the URL with key/value pair, Just like below

```
siege https://apicdntest.fadv.com/orders/kelly post MyXML='<root><test>test</test></root>'
```

Somebody please help me doing this in `siege` ?

Get result is below

```
Transactions:                      4 hits
Availability:                 100.00 %
Elapsed time:                   2.52 secs
Data transferred:               0.00 MB
Response time:                  0.26 secs
Transaction rate:               1.59 trans/sec
Throughput:                     0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:                    0.41
Successful transactions:           0
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            0.26
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

Post result

```
Transactions:                      0 hits
Availability:                   0.00 %
Elapsed time:                  16.20 secs
Data transferred:               0.00 MB
Response time:                  0.00 secs
Transaction rate:               0.00 trans/sec
Throughput:                     0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:                    0.00
Successful transactions:           0
Failed transactions:             4
Longest transaction:            0.00
Shortest transaction:           0.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reformatting your request like so:

```
siege "https://apicdntest.fadv.com/orders/kelly POST"
```

Note the quotes, which according to Jeffrey Fulmer (author of Siege) are [required](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/siege-users/sO-H1myTSM):  "Because POST urls contain spaces before and after POST, you must always quote them at the commandline."